# Typescript Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

(Sorry for bad English, I am not a native speaker)
I am having problem passing values to an object, and showing it in html.
Below are my codes:

```
  completeUserProfile = {};


  async testfunction() {
    const sampleArray = [1, 2];
    const interestRef = this.firestore.firestore.collection('interest');
    const result = interestRef.where('interestIn', 'array-contains-any', sampleArray).get();
    await result.then(querySnapshot => {
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        this.completeUserProfile[doc.data()['uid']] = {};
        this.completeUserProfile[doc.data()['uid']].uid = doc.data().uid;
        this.completeUserProfile[doc.data()['uid']].interestIn = doc.data().interestIn;
        this.completeUserProfile[doc.data()['uid']].updatedAt = doc.data().updatedAt.toDate();
        this.firestore.firestore.collection('userInformation').where('uid', '==', doc.data().uid).limit(1)
          .get().then((userInfo) => {
            userInfo.forEach(doc => {
              this.completeUserProfile[doc.data()['uid']].realName = doc.data().realName;
            })
          })
        console.log(this.completeUserProfile[doc.data()['uid']]);
      })
    });
  }
```

I can see the results in `console.log` without issue. However, I cannot get to display my information in html using ngFor loop. Even if I just `{{completeUserProfile }}`, I will get the result of `[object Object]`.

As I was dealing with Angular for the past month I realized I have to declare the object (in this case `completeUserProfile`) using `:` instead of `=`. But in this case I failed to do so. I need help. I appreciate for your time to read this.

Comment: You are trying to iterate on a Json property

Comment: I am new to this, I am not sure what is the Json property you are referring about. I would appreciate if you can tell me more exact on what I should do. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ngFor iterates over `arrays`, The error tells you so and `You are trying to iterate on a Json object.`

If you want to iterate over it, you either have to change it to an array, or you have to iterate on the keys. To do that :

```typescript
    completeUserProfileObject = [];
    
    this.completeUserProfileObjectKeys = Object.keys(this.completeUserProfile); // get keys
    this.completeUserProfileObject = Object.values(this.completeUserProfile); // get values
```

In your HTML :

```
<element *ngFor="let key of completeUserProfileObject">
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-iterate-object-keys-using-ngfor-ekucwl?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

Like the error message says, plain `*ngFor` only works for iterables like an array. You're trying to loop through an object. In this case you could try to use the [`keyvalue`](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) pipe (Angular v6.1+). It returns a collection of objects each with `key` and `value` property. They correspond to the respective property key and value from the source object.

Try the following

```html
<div *ngFor="let profile of completeUserProfile | keyvalue">
  {{ profile.key }}: {{ profile.value }}
</div>
```

Accordingly if you wish to render an object in the template, you need to use the [`json`](https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe) pipe.

```html
<div> {{ completeUserProfile | json }} </div>
```

If you're new to Angular, I'd recommend you to go through their [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial). It introduces some of the basics.